# Constructor, Member objects

Tags: c++, class

```
class Person{

public:
   Person(const string &nm, const string &surnm)
   : name(nm), surname(surnm)
   {

      cout << "\ntimes";
   }

private:
   string name;
   string surname;

};

class Family{

public:

  Family(Person &dad, Person &mom, Person &chld )
  : father(dad), mother(mom), child(chld)
  {
  }

private:

   Person father;
   Person mother;
   Person child;

};


int main(void){

  Person father1("John", "Gun");
  Person mother1("Marry", "Gun");
  Person child1("Alex", "Gun");

  Family firstFamily(father, mother, child);


  return 0;

}
```

When I compile this code, no error occurs.However, when I define "firstFamily" object, the memory for member objects `father`, `mother` ,and `child` is allocated. If memory is allocated for these objects, then constructor of class `Person` must be executed three times and I define three objects by using class `Person` in main method. Thus, constructor of `Person` class must be executed 6 times.However, it is executed for three times. Why is it three times ?( can reason be that I initialized father mother and child member objects in constructor class Family ? and that constructor is not executed for member objects. )

Comment: _"Thus, constructor of Person class must be executed 6 times."think so? makes you t_ Wha

Comment: *When I compile this code, no error occurs* -- It gives errors [here](http://ideone.com/m8svzn)

Comment: I believe the initialization of the Person objects in the Family constructor is using the compiler generated copy constructor which is not the same as your constructor.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well I think it's fairly minimal and almost verifiable (with some good will) ;-)

Comment: I think the current question is a much a better example for this kind of problem than the "duplicate", which is more about destructors in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

> Thus, constructor of Person class must be executed 6 times.However, it
>   is executed for three times.

Actually, there are 6 calls to a constructor of Person!
The first three times are the constructor created by yourself.

The other three times are when the *default copy constructor* created by the compiler will be called. This will be when the member variables of Family are initialized by the arguments of the Family constructor.

We can proof this by overriding the default copy constructor of Person:

```
class Person{

public:
   Person(const string &nm, const string &surnm)
   : name(nm), surname(surnm)
   {
      cout << "\ntimes";
   }

   Person(const Person& other) :
    name(other.name), surname(other.surname)
    {
        cout << "\ntimes2";   
    }

private:
   string name;
   string surname;
};
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7212d4918a61ceb9

I have also made a change to the constructor of Family to take its arguments by const reference. There is no need for a non-const reference here.